# What can we learn from the confidence interval of an interaction plot?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, data-visualization, interaction

Take the following interaction plot with 95% confidence interval. The CIs do overlap in some region, do not in others. What can conclude with this information? Can we claim whether the interaction term is statistically significant or not?

My confusion stems from the fact that interaction plot shows the difference in the two slopes and is thus a good way to visualize the magnitude. But to determine significance we still need the regression table. What then is the use of CIs in interaction plot?

[image: interaction plot]